# CakePHP 3.x Pass value from Javascript to PHP by ajax, $_POST is empty

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, cakephp

Ajax can alert the post data (`{"booking":{"testdata":"testdata"}}`) successfully. The problem is php code cannot get the `$_POST`.

Both of js and php exist in the same page: `localhost/booking/index.ctp`

Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
    <script>
                    $.ajax({

                            url: "<?php echo $this->Url->build([
                            "controller" => "booking",
                            "action" => "index",
                            "_ext" => "ctp",
                            true
                            ]);?>", //This is the current doc


                            type: "POST",
                            dataType:'json',
                            data: {'testdata': 'testdata'} ,
                            success: function(data){
                              //  console.log(data);
                                alert(JSON.stringify(data));
                            }
                        });

                    </script>

                    <?php
                    if (isset($_POST['testdata'])){
                        $getv = $_POST['testdata'];
                        echo json_encode($getv);
                    }
                    else {
                        echo "none";
                    }
                    ?>
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve with this code?

Answer (score 0):

this should be in controller

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['testdata'])){
    $getv = $_POST['testdata'];
    echo json_encode($getv);
}
else {
    echo "none";
}
?>
```

and you can use, in your controller:

```
public function initialize()
{
    $this->loadComponent('RequestHandler');
}
public function yourFunction()
{
    $yourvar = $this->request->getData('testdata');
    $this->set([
        'success' => true,
        'data' => $yourvar,
        '_serialize' => ['success', 'data']
    ]);
}
```

and in your ajax you can test this with the same code.

Comment: You mean that should _not_ be in a controller, because echoing data from controllers is a no-go (just like accessing superglobals directly) ;)